# Winforms MVP with Unity. Issue when injecting Views

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, unity-container, mvp

I’m writing a WinForms application and using some type of MVP pattern.

So far I have something like this:

```
var mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(someusercontrol);

public MainPresenter(MainView view) 
{
      var p = new MyPresenter(view.myView)
}

public MyPresenter(MyView view) 
{
      this.view = view;

    //Some code here…
      var user = new UserService().GetUser(1);
      this.view.FirstName = user.FirstName;
      this.view.LastName = user.LastName;
}
```

I’m skipping a lot of details but that’s the main idea and it’s working well so far.
Please note that “myView” is a usercontrol created in design time.

Now, I’m trying to add Unity and inject the views and services needed so I can unit test.

My code looks like:

```
var mainPresenter = new DependencyFactory.Container.Resolve<IMainPresenter>();

public MainPresenter(IMainView view, IMyPresenter myPresenter) 
{
}

public MyPresenter(IMyView view, IUserService userService) 
{
      this.view = view;

    //Some code here…
      var user = userService.GetUser(1);
      this.view.FirstName = user.FirstName;
      this.view.LastName = user.LastName;
}
```

I was able to make unity to create/inject “MyPresenter”, 
but the problem is that, as expected, it also creates a new MyView instace.  So in MyPresenter, instead of getting the user control on the screen (view.myView, created at design time) is getting a new instance of MyView (The one injected by Unity).

Can someone provide me some advice how this might be resolved or properly done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the lifetime management documentation for Unity.  Here's a good starting link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

Basically you need to figure out exactly what scenarios you need to support and make sure you use the correct lifetime manager.  In this case, it looks like you want Unity to create a MyView for MyPresenter and then pass that same view into MainPresenter, in which case you want the PerResolveLifetimeManager. It will spin up a single instance for each call to resolve.

Edit: Added sample below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IShared, Shared>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IChild, Child>();
        container.RegisterType<IParent, Parent>();

        var parent = container.Resolve<IParent>();

        var result = parent.Shared == parent.Child.Shared;

        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
        Console.WriteLine("Parent Instance Count: {0}", parent.Shared.InstanceCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Child Instance Count: {0}", parent.Child.Shared.InstanceCount);
    }
}

public interface IShared {
    int InstanceCount {get;}
}

public interface IChild {
    IShared Shared {get;}
}

public interface IParent
{
    IChild Child {get;}
    IShared Shared { get; }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public Child(IShared shared)
    {
        Shared = shared;
    }

    public IShared Shared
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public class Shared : IShared
{
    private static int _instanceCount = 0;
    private int _myInstanceNumber = 0;

    public Shared()
    {
        _instanceCount++;
        _myInstanceNumber = _instanceCount;
    }


    public int InstanceCount
    {
        get { return _myInstanceNumber; }
    }
}

public class Parent : IParent
{
    public Parent(IChild child, IShared shared)
    {
        Child = child;
        Shared = shared;
    }

    public IChild Child { get; private set; }

    public IShared Shared { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. 

But the issue is that "MyView" is being instantiated by the visual studio designer and I can't get the same object in "MyPresenter" to use it.